# Signing in with a specific user in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want a specific user form firebase to access the activity with if statement by comparing current user ID with this ID = 47NiYA7rGNa8nJvlnnxzpxhqvCl2.

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String USER = user.getUid();
if (USER == "47NiYA7rGNa8nJvlnnxzpxhqvCl2"){
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: How can manage firebase id for user?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works well with me.

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String currentUid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
if (currentUid == "47NiYA7rGNa8nJvlnnxzpxhqvCl2"){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

hope it helps you!